# Magento: How Search Box Results Are Generated

Tags: magento

I am a newbie in Magento and I have a question regarding the way the search box works.

If I understand correctly, the searchbox uses the catalogsearch_query table which is populated with the search terms the customers have entered in the input box. As a result these make up suggested results when someone types in a word.

The thing is, some of the customers may have entered something completely irrelevant to the store products (store that sells shirt dresses) e.g. black car with white stripes and it will show up as a result if the next customer types in the word 'black'.

Is there a way I can avoid something like that by manually modifying the code? If yes, what files would I have to change to achieve the required result?

Thank you for your time and your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is go to catalog in the admin and go to the catalog search tab, you can change the "search type" from "like" to "full text"  and it will search exact string,  however for this to be accurate attributes and titles have to be setup appropriately to your type of product.   I wish I had a direct answer but messing around changing the settings of attributes being searchable and changing the configuration of the search method are good areas to start.

[image]